# How do I improve ASP.NET MVC5 application performance on each page's first hit?

Tags: c#, performance, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

How do improve the performance of Asp.net MVC5 application. Especially my login page and layout page took more than one minute time to load while first time run.

Any one give me suggestion to improve the performance of MVC5 application.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Before applying random fixes/patches that will be proposed in answers here you need to understand core of your problem. Make sure to trace/profile your code that runs on first request to see what takes all that time.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can try:

A. Use the [Application Initialization plugin](http://forums.iis.net/t/1176740.aspx)

B. Use [Auto-Start with .NET 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

C. Disable the [idle-timeout (under IIS Reset)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808855/1080891)

D. [Precompile the site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is the link of original post:
[Fixing slow initial load for IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386471/fixing-slow-initial-load-for-iis)